# How to uninstall Homebrew of Rosetta and install Homebrew native on Mac Bigsu (M1)

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1, rosetta

Previously I have installed Homebrew rosetta version on MacOs M1,
now I see HomeBrew has native version, So how do I remove HomeBrew on rosetta and install the native version.
Please help me with this problem, Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Uninstall Rosetta version of Homebrew**

Run in rosetta mode inside terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

**Then install natively inside the terminal (without rosetta):**

(with help of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv2ylxro7rM)

```
cd /opt
sudo mkdir homebrew
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew
curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

(Add the Homebrew bin directory to the PATH if you are using zsh)

```
echo "export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: Do I need to remove a path for the Rosetta one?

Comment: You will not need to change the path as it will replace you automatically

Comment: thanks, when uninstalling, at the end I get the message `The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted` ... Do I need to delete any of those? If I'm just switching to M1 version. stuff like `/usr/local/Frameworks/`, or `/usr/local/Homebrew/`, `/usr/local/bin/`, and a few others

Comment: I don't think _all_ these steps are necessary anymore. In particular, I was able to install Homebrew on an M1 Mac using only the install script on the Homebrew homepage. Uninstalling the Intel version first (if you have one) is still a good idea.

Comment: How to remove Intel brew when I've installed the M1 one?

Comment: Thank you for your help! There was an old rosetta version of homebrew floating around and causing me issues when trying to build some apps, they were finding dependencies in the wrong location. Opening Terminal in Rosetta mode and running the uninstall script solved all my issues.