# tlsv1 protocol version error when trying to install homebrew on a new M1 Mac

Tags: ssl, curl, homebrew, apple-m1

I used Migration Assistant to move my account over to my new M1 Mac and am now trying to remove the old version of Homebrew [using these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242037/how-to-uninstall-homebrew-of-rosetta-and-install-homebrew-native-on-mac-bigsu-m).

When I try to run the uninstall script, though, I get this error:

```
√ ~ % arch -x86_64 /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I've updated my system to 12.3. My curl version is

```
curl 7.40.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0) libcurl/7.40.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8zd zlib/1.2.11
```

I'm stumped and would appreciate advice!

Comment: Also, I've tried just downloading the script and executing it. I get a message, "Script started, output file is typescript" and it writes a binary file named typescript in my dir. I don't know what to do with it or how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in a couple of places.

1. I was using an older version of curl, which I was confused by since it seemed like Apple would have had it all up to date. The version I was using, 7.40 was from /usr/local/bin. burtgummer45 on reddit helped me by [pointing out](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/thl24e/comment/i19aezu/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) that the version of curl in /usr/bin is 7.79.1. That helped a little bit, but then I ran into the missing .gitignore file.
2. DaniG2k's answer to [this question about porting Homebrew packages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410825/apple-silicon-port-all-homebrew-packages-under-usr-local-opt-to-opt-homebrew/410829#410829) to M1 Mac helped me to download the script and run it locally, bypassing my curl troubles. I did the same for the .gitignore and modified the script to find that in the working directory.

It wasn't pretty, but it took it off and now am rebuilding it with the M1 version.